# getPropertyValue function returns empty string on given DOM element in React TypeScript - How to read CSS vars in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, css-variables

I've made a simple utility function that should read given CSS variable using getPropertyValue function on `:root` element.

**Code**:

```
export const getCssVariable = (name: string): string => {
  const value = window
    .getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
    .getPropertyValue(name);

  return value;
};
```

This works if used in useEffect hook, but outside of it, **it returns an empty string.**

1. Why does this happen?
2. Is there another way to read CSS variables in React? Maybe through custom hook?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To access DOM elements, and by that also also their css property values, or computedStyle, your react code first needs to be mounted.
Writing code in `useEffect(() => // your code here, [])` ensures that the code is only run after your react code is mounted.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought.  That means the best way for something like this would be to create custom hook?

Comment: You can't call a custom hook like a function, like how you are doing it currently. However if you want to compute the CSS value on initial did mount or on state changes you can go for custom hook.